# How to get a list of database objects based on a set of column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm testing whether or not database objects exist based on some criteria. I'd like to able to verify whether or not a database object exists or not based on a supposed set of unique column names. Is this feasible in SQL Server 2012? I'm interested in an answer even if my test becomes obsolete because of good business reasons. This was my first instinct:

```
SELECT c.name AS 'ColumnName', t.name as 'TableName'
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
GROUP BY c.name, t.name
HAVING 
    c.name = 'column1'
    AND c.name = 'column2'
    AND c.name = 'column3'
```

From what I know about my current database I'm expecting this query to give me 3 records each displaying the expressed column and the same table name for all 3. However, this query gives me 0 results. I'm ignoring Views for now. Any suggestions?

- I need to grab any table that has these 3 exact columns (if those columns are used elsewhere without each-other I don't want them in my results).

Answer (score 1):

I probably wasn't clear enough in my question. I actually needed to make sure that all of the results were coming from the same object. I was basically looking for something like this:

```
SELECT c.object_id, t.name
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE
    c.name IN ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')
GROUP BY
    c.object_id, t.name
HAVING
    COUNT(c.object_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be changed, you need to use `IN` operator. That being said, you also don't need a `GROUP BY` clause as there are no aggregation(sum, min, max etc)  requirements. `HAVING` is generally used with a `GROUP BY` clause, therefore using `WHERE` here will fulfill your requirement. Try below code and see of you can get your desired results:

```
SELECT c.name AS 'ColumnName', t.name as 'TableName'
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    c.name in ('column1', 'column2', 'column3')
```

Comment: I've got an IN operator in my newest query but I'm still adjusting

Comment: This will return the result if any of the 3 columns exists and the Question is to get the table with all of the 3 columns

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh : Did you read the initial question? The one `originally posted` and my answer was to that `original question`. I don't keep track of edits which people might make days later.

Comment: But what you need to give is the solution for the problem, so sometimes you will have to keep track of it. or you can just change the solution now

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh I see that OP has figured it out. You are most welcome to write an answer. Sir.